# Page method returning 404 error to jquery post request in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis, pagemethods

I have created a Page Method, which is working fine on localhost, but not on live environment. Jquery call get the 404 error page in return.

**Asp.net 4.0**

**Local IIS Version: 7.5**

**Live IIS Version : 7.0**

**Example Live Web Page** : http://www.pricingindia.in/Store-Locator.aspx [Just share the location to execute the function]

Local Host screenshot : http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bc/d0/06/bcd0061d03597873d3204040d64f4077.jpg

**Page Method**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetLocalStores(decimal lat, decimal lon)
    {
        return GetData(lat,lon).GetXml();
    }
```

**Jquery Request**

```
function PullData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Store-Locator.aspx/GetLocalStores",
                data: '{lat: ' + latitude + ', lon: ' + longitude + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Web Config**

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```